# Why are some Titan Shifters able to harden their Titan bodies when most can't?

Tags: attack-on-titan

How can the Armored Titan and Annie in the Titan form harden their bodies, while Eren and the other Titan Shifters can't?

Comment: It appears that you're asking two different questions (one about Annie, and one about Eren); if so, it's best to split those up into separate posts.

Comment: Why should they all have the same ability? Also, Eren can harden his body. He use that to plug the hole in the wall that I forget what the name is.

Comment: I think the question is narrow enough now, please reopen it.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that Annie can harden her Titan form and Eren couldn't is because there are different types of Titan power in existence.

The complete explanation is as below.

**Massive Spoiler Alert**

> In the manga it is later revealed that all Titan powers came from Ymir Fritz, an ancient Fritz family monarch. According to Eldian mythology, over 1,820 years ago, Ymir came across what is only described as the "source of all organic material". With this discovery, Ymir gained the power of the Titans, becoming the 'Progenitor of all Titans'.
>
>  After 13 years Ymir met her death, and her "soul" was split between nine successors, giving these nine Titan powers. Throughout history, these powers are inherited by the 'Eldians' or the 'Subjects of Ymir'.
>
>  The Titan power that Eren possesses is called the 'Attack Titan'(進撃の巨人 Shingeki no Kyojin). The names of powers of other Titan Shifters is not yet revealed but they are also among the nine.
>
>  This the reason that the Titan Shifters possess different powers.
>
>  **Sources**
>
> - [Ymir Fritz](http://attackontitan.wikia.com/wiki/Ymir_Fritz)
> - [Eren Yeager](http://attackontitan.wikia.com/wiki/Eren_Yeager)

Comment: If you aren't aware, the name of Eren's titan is a namedrop for the Japanesr name of the series. The localization did not make it make note of the significance. I. E., Eren is literally the "Shingeki no Kyojin".